Why did my post just get edited? Why is meta full of old questions?
We're doing it again. This isn't really a question, more just an update for why meta doesn't look like it normally does.
In short, the meta FAQ was just updated to remove a bunch of bloat. As this resulted in the edits of about 30 posts to move the tags around and remove/add FAQ navigation links, the most recent posts on meta just before the edit were bumped afterwards to bring them back to the top. If there's a post we missed in bumping, feel free to make a minor edit to make sure it's not buried under this meta editing.
Otherwise, go about your day, nothing to see here, just Jedi business.
